# Cannot get the correct checked/unchecked value from checkbox

Tags: gwt, checkbox

I have created a checkbox :

```
final CheckBox enable = new CheckBox();
enableAccess.setValue( checked, true );
enableAccess.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick( ClickEvent event ) {
        //This works. Gives me the correct value
        ( ( CheckBox ) event.getSource() ).getValue();
        //This does not!!
        enable.getValue();
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me why this is so?

Comment: Because one checkbox is called enableAccess and the other one is called enable. The handler is on enableAccess not enable.

Answer (score 0):

Because one checkbox is called enableAccess and the other one is called enable. The handler is on enableAccess not enable.
This works fine for me.

```
final CheckBox enable = new CheckBox();
enable.setValue(true);
enable.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    System.out.println("A " + ((CheckBox) event.getSource()).getValue());
    System.out.println("B " + enable.getValue());
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Both are "enable". `enable.getValue()` works sometimes but not always.

Comment: "Sometimes but not always" looks very suspicious to me. Could you be more precise about the circumstances ? Maybe a piece of code getting in the way ?